# Referencing a property of an object from an another object

Tags: python

A little stuck on my code so I was wondering if you could help me out.

This is the part of the code that has been acting up:

```
def computerChoice():
    wVar2 = 0
    for aSeat in Seats:
        aSeat1 = aSeat
        while wVar2 < int(noOfSeats):
            print(aSeat1)
            if aSeat1.rightObject == "_":
                break
            elif aSeat1.rightObject.booked == False:
                aSeat1 = aSeat1.rightObject
                wVar2 += 1
            else:
                break
            possibleSeats.append(aSeat.co)
```

Where rightObject references another object from the same class.
It comes up with the error message:

```
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'booked'
```

With a couple of print statements I figured out that the while loop works the first time. It is only when aSeat1 is being reassigned and when a property of that is called that it turns to 0.

E.g. you can't just say

```
aSeat1.rightObject.rightObject.booked
```

Does anyone know how to fix this or do I just have to go at it from another angle?

EDIT: The initialisation of the class is as follows:

```
class Seat:
    def __init__ (self,seat_coordinate,seat_booked,seat_right,seat_right_object,seat_worth):
        self.co = seat_coordinate
        self.booked = seat_booked
        self.right = seat_right
        self.rightObject = seat_right_object
        self.worth = seat_worth
```

With an example object being:

```
   A1 = Seat("A1", False, "A2", A2, "A2", 0)
```

Thanks for all the responses so far

Comment: Could you provide definition of `aSeat` class?

Comment: Please include the code that shows how `aSeat.rightObject` is initialized. As a side note, the line `aSeat1 = aSeat` is totally useless.

Comment: From your error message, it is clear that `aSeat1.rightObect` returns an `int`. You then try to check if the `booked` attribute of an `int` is `False` which as you can see throws an error as there is no such attribute for an `int`. Maybe you meant `rightObject.booked == False`??

Comment: Thanks for the responses guys: kvorobiev - added. DYZ - it is because the aSeat1 changes within the while loop but I want to keep the aSeat in order to append it if the conditions are true. Joe aSeat1.rightObject doesn't immediately return an int. On the first iteration it obediently returns an object. However when it is then set to aSeat1 and an object is taken from that in that case it returns an int for some reason - hence the question.

Comment: Unrelated to your other issues, `aSeat1.rightObject.booked == False` is more idiomatically written as `not aSeat1.rightObject.booked`. You almost never need to do equality comparisons with Boolean values.

Comment: Your example of a call to `Seat` doesn't match the `__init__` method you've shown. They have different numbers of arguments, which makes it hard to tell if you're actually passing in another `Seat` object as the `seat_right_object` parameter. The exception suggests you're passing an invalid value at some point when building up your data structure, so I'd look very carefully at those calls, even if this specific error is only in the code you've given us.